# How to combine and modify ggplot2 legends with ribbons and lines?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have several issues with the legend on the following plot:
[image]

- Ribbons and lines are separated into 2 different legends, but I want them to be merged: lines in legend should have background fill that corresponds to the ribbon with the same name (and transparent for the "official tax" entry).
- Lines in the legend differs by colour but they should differ by colour AND linetype.

Seems that I need to use `scale_manual` and `guide_legend` options, but all my attempts failed miserably.

Here is the code to create the plot. `plotDumping` is the function that draws the plot, `updateData` generates data frame for the plot and 'updateLabels' generates footnote for the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(scales)

max_waste_volume <- 2000 
Illegal_dumping_fine_P <- 300000
Illigal_landfilling_fine_P1 <- 500000
Fine_probability_k <- 0.5
Official_tax_Ta <- 600

# mwv = max_waste_volume
# P = Illegal_dumping_fine_P
# P1 = Illigal_landfilling_fine_P1
# k = Fine_probability_k
# Ta = Official_tax_Ta


updateData <- function(mwv, k, P1, P, Ta){

    # creates and(or) updates global data frame to provide data for the plot

    new_data <<- NULL
    new_data <<- as.data.frame(0:mwv)
    names(new_data) <<- 'V'
    new_data$IlD <<- k*P1/new_data$V
    new_data$IlD_fill <<- new_data$IlD
    new_data$IlD_fill[new_data$IlD_fill > Ta] <<- NA # we don't want ribbon to 
    new_data$IlL <<- Ta-k*P/new_data$V
}

updateLabels <- function(k, P1, P, Ta){

    ### creates footnote caption for the plot

    prob <- paste('Fining probability = ', k, sep = '')
    landfilling_fine <- paste('Illegal landfilling fine = ', P1, sep = '')
    dumping_fine <- paste('Illegal dumping fine = ', P, sep = '')
    tax <- paste('Official tax = ', Ta, sep = '')
    note <<- paste(prob, landfilling_fine, sep = '; ')
    note <<- paste(note, dumping_fine, sep = '; ')
    note <<- paste(note, tax, sep = '; ')
    note
}


plotDumping <- function(mwv, 
                        P,
                        P1,
                        k,
                        Ta){

  ### this function draws the plot

  # initialise plot data
  updateData(mwv, k, P1, P, Ta)
  updateLabels(k, P1, P, Ta)

  # draw the plot
  profit <- ggplot(data=new_data, aes(x = new_data$V)) +
    geom_ribbon(show_guide = T, alpha = 0.25, ymax = Ta, 
                aes(ymin = new_data$IlD_fill,
                    fill = "Illegal landfill owner's\nprofitable ratio\n")) +
    geom_ribbon(show_guide = F, alpha = 0.25, ymin = 0, 
                aes(ymax = new_data$IlL, 
                    fill = "Waste owner's\nprofitable ratio")) + 
    geom_line(data=new_data, 
              aes(y = new_data$IlD, col = "Illegal landfill owner's\nprofitable ratio\n"), 
              size = 1,
              linetype = 4) +
    geom_line(data=new_data, 
              aes(y = new_data$IlL, col = "Waste owner's\nprofitable ratio"), 
              size = 1,
              linetype = 5) + 
    geom_line(y = Ta, 
              aes(col = "Official tax"), 
              size = 1.5,
              linetype = 1)+ 
    xlim(c(0, max(new_data$V)))+
    ylim(c(0, Ta*1.5))+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, hjust = 0),
          axis.title = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 14),
          title = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 16),
          legend.position = 'right',
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
          legend.key.width = unit(1, 'cm'))+
    labs(title="Profitable ratio between the volume \nof illegally disposed waste \nand costs of illegal waste disposure",
         x="Waste volume, cubic meters",
         y="Cost per cubic meter, RUB")

   # add a footnote about paramaters used for the current plot
   profit <- arrangeGrob(profit, sub = textGrob(note, 
                                           x = 0, 
                                           hjust = -0.1, 
                                           vjust=0.1, 
                                           gp = gpar(fontface = "italic", fontsize = 12)))

 # show plot
 print(profit)
}

# draw the plot
plotDumping(max_waste_volume, 
                         Illegal_dumping_fine_P,
                         Illigal_landfilling_fine_P1,
                         Fine_probability_k,
                         Official_tax_Ta)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your version to also get the correct linetype, if you put the linetype insidt the `aes` function. However, your code becomes even more cumbersome that way. Consider reshaping your data before calling `ggplot`. Then you don't have to worry about the legend at all.

```
# reshape data ...
new_data$Ta <- Ta
new_data$zero <- 0
require(reshape2)
dta <- melt(new_data, id.vars="V", measure.vars=c("IlD", "IlL", "Ta"))
dta.lower <- melt(new_data, id.vars="V", measure.vars=c("IlD_fill", "zero", "Ta"))
dta.upper <- melt(new_data, id.vars="V", measure.vars=c("Ta", "IlL", "Ta"))
dta <- cbind(dta, lower=dta.lower$value, upper=dta.upper$value)
dta$name <- factor(NA, levels=c("Illegal landfill owner's\nprofitable ratio\n",
                                "Waste owner's\nprofitable ratio", 
                                "Official tax"))
dta$name[dta$variable=="IlD"] <- "Illegal landfill owner's\nprofitable ratio\n"
dta$name[dta$variable=="IlL"] <- "Waste owner's\nprofitable ratio"
dta$name[dta$variable=="Ta"] <- "Official tax"
```

Now tha plotting command becomes much easier and more transparent:

```
ggplot(dta, aes(x=V, y=value, ymin=lower, ymax=upper, 
                color=name, fill=name, linetype=name)) +
  geom_line(size=1.2) + ylim(c(0, Ta*1.5)) +
  geom_ribbon(alpha=.25, linetype=0) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, hjust = 0),
        axis.title = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 14),
        title = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 16),
        legend.position = 'right',
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.key.width = unit(2, 'cm'))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(4, 5, 1)) +
  labs(title="Profitable ratio between the volume \nof illegally disposed waste \nand costs of illegal waste disposure",
       x="Waste volume, cubic meters",
       y="Cost per cubic meter, RUB")
```

Answer (score 3):

One workaround in this situation would be to add `geom_ribbon()` also for the `Official tax` (using value `Ta` as `ymax` and `ymin`). This will make both legend with the same levels and they will be joined together. Then with `scale_fill_manual()` you can set fill value for `Official tax` to NA and then in legend for this level fill will be as background.

```
+ geom_ribbon(show_guide = F, alpha = 0.25, ymin = Ta,ymax=Ta, 
            aes(fill = "Official tax"))

+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F8766D",NA,"#00BFC4"))
```

[image]

P.S. Do not use the `$` inside the `aes()` of `ggplot()` functions (use just column names). As you already wrote `data=new_data` all variables inside the `aes()` are looked for in this data frame.

Comment: Nice workaround, thank you. I have to use `$` inside `aes` because otherwise my function will fail to work correctly with `manipulation` library.